# How do I Perform installation through command prompt?

Tags: installation

I am trying to perform installation (*.exe) through Command prompt. I am able to start the installation but I want to continue the complete installation of an *.exe without using the mouse, meaning I have to give Next and select the product to be installed everything through the command prompt. Can anyone help me how to do that or give me a direction? 
Since this is my 1st post please correct me the way I ask for help if I am wrong.
Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to install? Please refer to link for asking question.[How to ask good question] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried to make my question generic. For example I am trying to install VLC media player.

Answer (score 0):

If the installation is supported from command prompt by the software vendor then only it can be done, otherwise not.

Please check with the installation instruction of the software you are trying to install.